# Bayesian Model Averaging and gamboostLSS with longitudinal data.

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, panel-data, model-selection, fixed-effects-model

Im using the above methods for model selection with longitudinal data. My question is; do I have to account for fixed and random effects when performing the variable selection? If yes, are there any standard procedures to do so that can easily be implemented in R or Matlab?

Cheers

J